# Integration tests don't use configuration from Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing

In Startup class I added some configuration to ConfigureServices method. For example I added AutoMapper

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAutoMapper();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

My class TestFixture configure enviroment for integration tests.

```
public class TestFixture : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IContainer _container;

        public TestFixture()
        {
            var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
                .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac()));

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterModule(new TestModule());
            _container = builder.Build();
        }

        public TEntity Resolve<TEntity>()
        {
            return _container.Resolve<TEntity>();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _container.Dispose();
            OasisDataContext.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Without services.AddAutoMapper() in TestFixture class AutoMapper won't work, but Startup class has configuration for AutoMapper. 
Why do integration test not use configuration for services from Startup if TestStartup derived from Startup class?